# Order/context-aware document / sentence to vectors in Spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy, text-classification, document-classification, spacy-transformers

I would like to do some supervised binary classification tasks with sentences, and have been using spaCy because of its ease of use. I used spaCy to convert the text into vectors, and then fed the vectors to a machine learning model (e.g. XGBoost) to perform the classfication. However, the results have not been very satisfactory.

In spaCy, it is easy to load a [model](https://spacy.io/models/en-starters) (e.g. BERT / Roberta / XLNet) to convert words / sentences to nlp objects. Directly calling the vector of the object will however will [default](http://Doc.vector%20and%20Span.vector%20will%20default%20to%20an%20average%20of%20their%20token%20vectors.) to an average of the token vectors.

Here are two questions:

1) Can we do better than simply getting the average of token vectors, like having context/order-aware sentence vectors using spaCy? For example, can we extract the sentence embedding from the previous layer of the BERT transformer instead of the final token vectors in spaCy?

2) Would it be better to directly use spaCy to train the downstream binary classification task? For example, here [discusses](https://spacy.io/usage/training) how to add a text classifier to a spaCy model. Or is it generally better to apply more powerful machine learning models like XGBoost?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found this being discussed in the page below. Maybe it helps.

"Most people usually only take the hidden states of the [CLS] token of the last layer - using the hidden states for all tokens or from multiple layers doesn't usually help you that much."

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/1950